# Probability density function convolution in python: how to efficiently?

Tags: python, math, scipy, statistics

Given that this is a fairly long post, I think it's best if I start with my question: What is the best way of implementing this model in python?

I'm developling a statistical model that involves the convolution of probability density functions. Without giving away what I can't, here is my problem:

Parameter A describes the time from t0 to event A at t1. It is given by a uniform distribution with lower and upper bounds a and b respectively.

```
A ~ U(a, b)
```

Parameter B describes the time from t1 to event B at t2. It is also given by a uniform distribution with lower and upper bounds c and d respectively.

```
B ~ U(c, d)
```

Parameter G describes the time from t0 to event C, at an unknown time. It is given by a gamma distribution with shape and scale parameters alpha and beta, with mean = alpha / beta and standard deviation = alpha / (beta ^ 2).

```
G ~ G(alpha, beta)
```

We would like to know the probability that G falls between t1 and t2. We would also like to perform a grid search over these parameters, so it is important that the calculation is completed efficiently. The target end user includes civil service agencies who do not have access to high performance computing (like we do), so parallellisation is not an option.

The time at which t1 occurs is given by A, however the time at which t2 occurs is given as the sum of A and B

```
Y = A + B

W = A - G

Z = Y - G
```

As these two distributions are uniform, they may be analytically convolved. The probability that G occurs between A and Y is given as P(A < G < Y). We can introduce variables Y and Z as above:

```
P(A < G < Y) = P(W < 0 < Z)
P(A < G < Y) = P(Z > 0) - P(W > 0)
P(A < G < Y) = [1 - P(Z < 0)] - [1 - P(W < 0)]
P(A < G < Y) = Fw(0) - Fz(0)
```

Fw(0) and Fz(0) refer to the cumulitive density functions of distributions Y and Z respectively.

[Fw(0) can be calculated as shown in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHvg.png)

[For Fz(0), a triple integral is required.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTBpO.png)

What would be the best way of computing this maths in python? We have a working program, but it is slow even when we constrain the integration bounds and analytically convolve A and B to give Y. The strategy is to convolve numerically, using quad from scipy.integrate. This is slow and frequently gives us roundoff errors and overruns the maximum number of subdivisions.

Is there a better way?

We can verify the results of the program against two existing implementations, one programmed in fortran but utilising NAG library integration routines, and another written in matlab. The fortran version is satisfactory for our own scientific research, but our motivation for using python is to produce a distributable source code written in a freely available language using open source routines such as those in the Scipy library. The use of NAG library routines percludes this from fortran.

Comment: Are you sure about the validity of the formula `P(A < G < Y) = Fw(0) - Fz(0) (=P(G>A) - P(G<Y))`?

Comment: Convolutions are typically computed via fast Fourier transform. Discretize the pdf's and convolve the discretizations. The result is a discrete approximation to the resulting pdf. You have to be careful details or the results will be slightly off. I can find some code (Java) that I wrote a long time ago, but it's not very complicated and I'm sure there is already FFT in Python so it should be straightforward.